# Iterate over array in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to iterate over this and put this into ng-repeat. So instead of [0] I need the whole array.(Iv'e just pulled the first one [0] so I can get the object)

```
<img ng-src="{{hotelImage[0].url}}" class="img-responsive">


<div ng-repeat image in hotelImage>
    {{image}}
    <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" width="60">
</div>
```

Comment: solution change into `ng-repeat="image in hotelImage"`. use proper angular IDE , so can you show your error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat on img tag directly. So assuming you rename your array to hotelImages:

```
<img ng-repeat="hotelImage in hotelImages" ng-src="{{hotelImage.url}}" class="img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your ng-repeat syntax first
Check this :

```
<img ng-src="{{hotelImage[0].url}}" class="img-responsive">
<div ng-repeat="image in hotelImage">
    {{image.url}}
    <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" width="60">
</div>
```